# MongoDB insert from NODEJS converts data type of value from int to string

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update an integer from NodeJS to a MongoDB collection, and however ways I have tried it always converts the integer into a string in the collection.

Please note, I cannot have a strict mongoose schema.

Here's my update function:

```
 _getModel("envSettings").update(query, toUpdate , {upsert: insertIfNotFound}, function(err, docs){
   _prepResponse(err, docs, callback);
 });
```

The inputs to this piece of code is like this:

```
insertIfNotFound: false
query: {'_id':'somekey'}
```

And here are the variety of toUpdate I have tried:

```
toUpdate: {$set:{value: 70}}
toUpdate: {$set:{value: parseInt(70)}}
toUpdate: {$set:{value: mongodb.Long(70).toInt()}}
```

When printing any of the above toUpdate to console, the output is always the same:

```
{'$set':{value:70}}
```

I am unsure of how can I save the type of field, please?

Comment: How have you defined your mongoose schema?

Comment: I have a mongoose schema, but the "value" field can be of two different kinds - integer, string. Hence, the schema is loosely coupled (strict is false)

Comment: To check all three variation use `typeof`because display in print function will be same always. It is my personal preference to Insert all as string and while displaying check for numeric value, if you find value to be numeric then process it accordingly. Also storing all data as string will help you in making your queries as well

Comment: There's a python script that reads certain properties from this collection, and it expects this form as int.  I am avoiding to change code there.

Comment: What are you trying to console?

Comment: Trying to make sure that I am not inserting string type, just a verification.

Comment: @shahmanthan9 could you add your comment as an answer? Would want to upvote on that and accept it.

Comment: @swateek There you go :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check all three variation use `typeof` because display in print function will be same always. 
It is my personal preference to Insert all as string and while displaying check for numeric value, if you find value to be numeric then process it accordingly.

Also storing all data as string will help you in making your queries as well.

Edit - I used the second approach for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a property `value` declared in your schema of type `String`:

```
value : String
```

This will make Mongoose cast values to string, *regardless* of the `strict` setting (which is not related to casting but whether or not to allow undeclared properties in your documents).

You should declare it as a `Number` instead, because you're writing *"there's a python script that reads certain properties from this collection, and it expects this form as int"*. In other words: you want documents in the database to have a numerical `value` field.

This will still allow string valued `value` fields serving as input to Mongoose operations, because Mongoose will cast them to numbers before writing to the database.

If you want to allow both strings and numbers to be written as-is to the database, you need to use [`mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed). This basically means that Mongoose will allow *anything* as input, and it will write the value as-is to the database (no casting). However, since you're saying that the Python tool expects numbers, I'd expect that you want to make sure that numbers are written to the database.

Comment: I cannot do this one, as there are string values too in the collection. Just that I am using mongoose in my node app, I am obligated to have a collection.

Comment: Mongoose doesn't mind if there are strings in the collection already, it will cast them to `Number` when creating the document instance (for instance, when querying the collection). But if you really want to allow both strings and numbers to end up in the database, see my edit.